# Анимация в блендере Emotecraft

Tags: blender, minecraft, animate

такая проблема я создаю эмоций для игры майнкрафте с помощью блендера и мне в некоторых анимация нужно чтобы какая то часть постоянно повторялась простой способ с модефикацей cycles мне не подходить потому что в игре не видно что оно постоянно повторяется подскажите как можно это обыграть?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы какая-то часть вашей анимации в игре повторялась, вы можете попробовать использовать технику, называемую "**текстурированием смещения**". Это позволяет вам перемещать текстуру по поверхности объекта, что создает эффект движения.

Вам нужно создать текстуру, которую вы хотите перемещать, и затем применить ее к объекту в Blender. Затем вы можете настроить параметры смещения текстуры, чтобы **создать нужный эффект движения**.

Когда вы экспортируете анимацию в формат, поддерживаемый игрой Minecraft, текстура смещения также должна **экспортироваться вместе с ней**. Таким образом, когда вы запустите анимацию в игре, часть с текстурой смещения будет **постоянно повторяться**.

Если у вас возникнут проблемы с настройкой текстурирования смещения в Blender, вы можете найти множество ресурсов и видеоуроков онлайн, которые помогут вам освоить эту технику.

Comment: Ответ выглядит, как будто писала chatGPT